# Custom thumbnail

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

I wonder if there is a way to customize thumbnail generation for the source model, and we can even impact on rendering quality?
For now, right after successful translation to 'SVF', we use [Get Thumbnail API](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/thumbnails/urn-thumbnail-GET/).
Here is a sample of thumbnail we get when requesting 400x400 size.
[Sample of generated thumbnail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BIHdM.png)

Will appreciate any comments on this

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thumbnails from Model Derivative are generated by default in three sizes, 100x100, 200x200, and 400x400 (refer [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/developers_guide/basics/thumbnail_generation/))

Please note that you can also take advantage of Viewer's [getScreenShot](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/Viewer3D/#getscreenshot-w-h-cb-overlayrenderer) method.

You can also check [this blog post](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/more-screenshots) on that